# How to upload data stored in database to an URL in android

Tags: android, sqlite, url

I am working in an app based on network. My app works good when network is available. I want the same process to be done when network is not available too.

For that when the user feeds some data in the edit boxes of the app when network is not available, I have stored all those values in a Sqlite database.

In another activity of the app when the user clicks a button, at that time if network is available I want the data's stored in the database to be moved over to the url.

I want to know how to read the data stored in db in another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean another activity of your application, than you could easily connect to DB, fetch data and send it to URL. application DB could be shared between all activities of application and does not depend on which page of your app data was saved.

If you want to do it from another app, then you should use ContentProvider. Refer [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you could use an intermediary service (such as a php script etc) and send your data in the form of a URL page request for it to store the data on the webpage.
for example if you would like to create a new record on the URL.
you could then send http://myhost.com/update.php?name=xyz?value=23 or something like that I assume.

I would say that making your android manipulate a static webpage( if thats what you are trying to do ) is rather a overhead and unnecessary.